# "undefined reference to `WinMain@16'" Error in gcc editor

Tags: c++, gcc, codeblocks

I am just learning c++ and began to watch a youtube tutorial by thenewboston. Unfortunately he is using Code::Blocks while I am using gcc and I do not have the option to create new class files with a button click and so had to manually create them.

I dont understand why the same code in Code::Blocks and gcc will work in Code::Blocks but not gcc. Does gcc require different coding for the same language?

EDIT: I have downloaded and tested in Code::Blocks myself

Other questions talk of how I need to give windows an entry point, but I dont know how to do that.

Test.cpp Code:

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include "ClassTest.h"
> using namespace std;
>
> int main() {
>   ClassTest bo;
> }
> ```

ClassTest.h Code:

> ```
> #ifndef CLASSTEST_H
> #define CLASSTEST_H
>
> class ClassTest {
>   public:
>       ClassTest();
> };
>
> #endif // CLASSTEST_H
> ```

ClassTest.cpp Code:

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include "ClassTest.h"
> using namespace std;
>
> ClassTest::ClassTest() {
>   cout << "blah blah" << endl;
> }
> ```

Comment: How are you compiling this code?

Comment: Code::Blocks is an IDE, and GCC is a compiler.   Code::Blocks can use GCC to compile, though.  Also note, that for c++ code, use `g++`, not `gcc`.

Comment: You created a Windows project instead of a Console project.

Comment: newboston is a terrible resource. Have you created a Windows console project?

Comment: Okay, so I will need to download and use g++ instead of gcc?

Comment: g++ almost always comes as a part of GCC. Code::Blocks usually uses GCC tools for compiling, so you should already have it. I've tagged the question `codeblocks` to hopefully attract the eyes f someone who knows how to explain Code::Blocks's different project types.

Comment: `g++` and `gcc` are two programs; `g++` compiles C++ and `gcc` compiles C. But they usually come together in a package also called GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection. The real thing you are missing that Code::Blocks provides and GCC by itself does not is a build system, which will compile your different cpp files one at a time and then link them together into a program.

Comment: How do I get a build system then? Just use Code::Blocks?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I understand what the question is; I'm going to take it as "how do I get these three files to build into a .exe that I can run from the Windows commmand line?"

The answer is to run something like this on the command line, in the folder with the files:

```
g++ -c Test.cpp -o Test.o
g++ -c ClassTest.cpp -o ClassTest.o
g++ Test.o ClassTest.o -o Test.exe
```

The first two commands build each CPP file into an "object file", which isn't a whole program by itself but which contains the compiled version of the code in that CPP file. The last command tells the compiler to paste together the two object files into a program, and resolve all the cross-references between them. (For example, the part where Test.cpp constructs a ClassTest object needs to end up calling the ClassTest constructor code from ClassTest.cpp.)

Code::Blocks is an IDE and works out how to build each source file in your project and link them together by itself. But if you aren't using an IDE, you need to do that in another way. You can either do it manually like this, or you can write a [Makefile](http://mrbook.org/blog/tutorials/make/) that will check which code files have changed and rebuild and re-link everything that depends on them when you run the `make` command, which is how most people do it.

As for "giving Windows an entry point", that probably refers to GUI applications that want to display windows on the screen. For console programs like the one you have written, the "entry point" is `main()`, and you just print stuff to the command line window. To make actual Windows-style GUI windows of your own, you need to use the Windows API, which I can't tell you much about.

Comment: More simply you could just say `g++ Test.cpp ClassTest.cpp -o Test.exe`